# rvm passenger nginx

Tags: nginx, rvm, passenger

I am trying to deploy my app to a VPS with capistrano, rvm, passenger & nginx.

I already had installed nginx via apt-get on Debian6.

Now it appears as though to install passenger and to run `passenger-install-nginx-module` I have to run both commands as sudo according to modrails site.

The problem is that I installed rvm system wide using sudo. Now it doesn't seem to allow sudo gem installs. I am having a tough time understanding all the ins & outs of rvm.

For example this link http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration suggests updating rvm by

> rvm update --head

**That gives the error:**

> ERROR: rvm update has been removed. See 'rvm get' and rvm 'rubygems'
>   CLI API instead

So one thing leads to another error and another thing which needs upgrading etc.
 I would really like some help with these questions:

- On a server should rvm be installed using sudo?
- If not I won't be able to run the passenger module installation
  commands.
- rvm web site strongly discourages system wide installs as written on
  https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems/. When it IS installed system wide how do you run sudo gem install passenger?

I feel I am in a catch-22 situation here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I did a bit more digging and used rvmsudo to install both and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `sudo` with RVM, it loses all shell variables - including those needed for RVM / Ruby to work correctly.

To update RVM run:

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
```

For installing gems when RVM is installed in `/usr/local/rvm` make sure your user is in **rvm** group, you can verify it with:

```
id
```

Here is the [best practices deployment using RVM and SM Framework](https://rvm.io/deployment/best-practices/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I did figure some of the solutions at rvm.io. But SM framework looks great. I will look into that later.